# Moving from create_proc_read_entry to proc_create and using seq_files

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to move from the deprecated function `create_proc_read_entry` to using `proc_create`.  I've been doing research into the new implementation that uses seq_files.  Previously I was using the `/proc` file system to pass a pointer to a struct that I `copy_from_user` to kernel space.  This struct has info in it (and other data) that I use to determine what function is called next.  I'm struggling with the newer implementation.  Specifically how I can get that pointer to the struct that is passed from user space.  From my research the seq_files implementation uses the seq files to conveniently iterate through structures without having to deal with the pointer stuff.

```
struct sCmd_t {
    u32 length;
    u8 type;
    int number;
    u16 command;
    u8 version;
} sCmd_t

ctrl_file = create_proc_read_entry("ctrl",
                                   0666,
                                   PROC_FILE,
                                   read_proc_ctrl,
                                   NULL);

ctrl_file->write_proc = write_proc_ctrl;

static int write_proc_ctrl( struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, unsigned long len, void *data){

    sCmd_t *sCmd = NULL;
    const unsigned char *curbuf = NULL;

    sCmd = (sCmd_t *) kmalloc(sizeof(sCmd_t), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (sCmd == NULL)
          return ERROR;

    memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(sCmd));

    curbuf = buff;

    if (copy_from_user( cmd, curbuf, sizeof(sCmd_t)))
            return -EFAULT;

    switch (sCmd->command){
     //based on the command the appropriate
    }
```

So what I'm trying to do is grab the pointer to my struct from the seq_show function, but it's not working.

```
static int seq_show(struct seq_file *seqfile, void *v)
{
    //in here I'm trying to grab a pointer to the struct here
    sCmd_t *sCmd = NULL;
    const unsigned char *curbuf = NULL;

    sCmd = (sCmd_t *) kmalloc(sizeof(sCmd_t), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (sCmd == NULL)
          return ERROR;

    memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(sCmd));

    curbuf = v;

    if (copy_from_user( cmd, curbuf, sizeof(sCmd_t)))
//blah blah blah.....

    return 0;
}

static void *seq_start(struct seq_file *seqfile, loff_t *pos)
{
    return pos;
 }

static void *seq_next(struct seq_file *seqfile, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    return pos;
}

static void seq_stop(struct seq_file *seqfile, void *v)
{
   return;
}

static struct seq_operations seq_ops = {
    .start  = seq_start,
    .next   = seq_next,
    .stop   = seq_stop,
    .show   = seq_show
};

static int proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    return seq_open(file, &seq_ops);
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
 .owner     = THIS_MODULE,
 .open      = proc_open,
 .read      = seq_read,
 .llseek    = seq_lseek,
 .release   = single_release,
 };

ctrl_file = proc_create("ctrl", 0644, proc_dir, &fops);
```

This is just a first attempt.  When I try this code it pukes when I deref the command member of the struct.  As you can see my struct is pretty small so it's not like this implementation will have to use the seq files to check if the it's running onto another page.  That's why I tried to grab the pointer in the show function as I would imagine it would have to iterate or "next" to the struct or page.  From what I've read the seq_file iteration will make it easy to iterate through structs but I first need to understand how to get a pointer to what I write to the `/proc` file system from user space.

Comment: Your original problem, how to tell the new proc API about the write callback, is solved. As for correctly handling buffers, that would be a new question; consider posting it separately. (And when you do, include the definition of `cmd`.)

Comment: yup you are right.  My seg fault issue is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seq_file` is a helper for implementing a read-only file.
The buffer of the `show` callback is a kernel buffer where you are supposed to write the data that is to be returned to user space.

You can choose to use `seq_file`, or not; but it would not make sense here.

But in any case, procfs operations are defined with `struct file_operations`;
to implement a write callback, just implement `write` in `fops`.

Comment: thanks for the reply - so the callbacks for the proc file have been moved from the proc_dir_entry struct to the file_operations struct?  And now the file_operations struct refers the the proc file?

Comment: Don't edit your question as a reply to an answer; this would make any existing answers invalid, and confuse anybody finding this page through Google.